# PANDAS find exact given string/word from a column

Tags: python, pandas, text-mining

So, I have a pandas column name **Notes** which contains a sentence or explanation of some event. I am trying find some given words from that column and when I find that word I am adding that to the next column as **Type**

The problem is for some specific word for example **Liar**, **Lies** its picking up word like **familiar** and **families** because they both have liar and lies in them.

```
Notes                                  Type
2 families are living in the address   Lies
He is a liar                           Liar
We are not familiar with this          Liar
```

As you can see from above only the second sentence is correct. How do I only pick up separate word like liar, lies and not families or familiar.

This was my approach,

```
word= ["Lies"]

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    for f in word:
        if f in df["Notes"][i]:
            df["Type"][i] = "Lies"
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: [pandas.Series.str.match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\b` for word boundary in  `regex`, and `.str.extract` to find pattern:

```
 df.Notes.str.extract(r'\b(lies|liar)\b')
```

To label those rows containing that word, do:

```
df['Type'] = np.where(df.Notes.str.contains(r'\b(lies|liar)\b'), 'Lies', 'Not Lies')
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I assign the Type based on the line then?

Comment: `df['Type'] =  df.Notes.str.extract(r'\b(lies|liar)\b')[0]`? maybe chain that with `.str.capitalize()`

Comment: I wanted to assign the Type as "Lies" for those words. Any way to do that?

Comment: Thanks. The code works perfectly but just a small issue. If you assign a different Type again for a different word it just overwrites the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Well I agree with Quang Hoang answer. Please make sure you are aware about sentences like "He is not a liar". Where it will still match and give you Liar.

Answer (score 0):

I think this piece if code will work fine for you!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Notes":["2 families are living in the address"  ,
"He is a liar  "              ,           
"We are not familiar with this "   ]  }) 



word= ["liar","are","this"]
found_in_whole_string =[]

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    found_one_word=[]
    for f in word:
        if f in df["Notes"][i].split(" "):
            found_one_word.append(f)
        else:
            found_one_word.append("")
    found_in_whole_string.append(",".join([word for word in found_one_word if len(word) > 0])  )

df["type"] = found_in_whole_string
```